# Simplifying a square root fraction

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, radicals

Simplify the following

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{3})}$$

Apparently the answer is $\frac{1}{2} (2 + \sqrt{2})$ but can't for the life of me see how to get it.  Any help is massively appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2 (\sqrt 6 - \sqrt 3)} = \dfrac{\sqrt 3}{\sqrt 2 \sqrt 3(\sqrt2 - 1)} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt 2 (\sqrt 2 - 1)} = \dfrac{1}{(2 - \sqrt 2)} = \dfrac{(2 + \sqrt 2)}{(2 - \sqrt 2)(2 + \sqrt 2)} = \dfrac{2 + \sqrt 2}{2}$

The reason we write it this way is that it is bad practice to have roots at the denominator. To get rid of $a+b \sqrt c$ at the denominator, simply multiply the numerator and the denominator by $a-b \sqrt c$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I was really just missing your first step of factorising the bracket in the denominator.  Anyway nice solution and thanks for your help.

Comment: Why is it "bad practice to have roots in the denominator"?

Answer (score 3):

$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3})}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{1})}=\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac12(2+\sqrt{2}).$

Comment: Ok Paul I can see how you got there.  Thanks for your response.